# APNS € and ¢ and $ signs

Tags: php, character-encoding, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send a push notification containing a special character (like €, ¢ or $). But the message eventually appears like: € => Û. What is the script doing:

```
$this->message = "Test special sign €";    
$message = utf8_encode($this->message);
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message,
        'badge' => '1',
        'sound' => 'default'
);
$body['e'] = $this->event;
$body['i'] = $this->eventId;

$this->payload  = json_encode($body);
var_dump($this->payload);
```

OUTPUT: var_dump($this->payload) 
string(118) "{"aps":{"alert":"Test special sign \u00db","badge":"1","sound":"default"},"e":"order","i":"12"}"

Packing the message and send it.

```
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', trim($RegisterIds[$key]['registerId'])) . pack('n', strlen($this->payload)) . $this->payload;
```

It is possible to send the euro sign? And if so... How? (Or what am I doing wrong?)

Comment: All files are properly UTF-8 encoded saved.

Comment: Are you sure that the encoding of $this->message is ISO-8859-1 before utf8_encode() ?

Comment: @SamuilBanti. No, removed the utf8_encode after reading the deceze post. It is UTF-8 before. (checked with mb_detect_encoding)

Comment: You should check the encoding headers on the location where you view the message. Is it stored in a database? And as a workaround may be you can use &euro; (if you will display it in browsers)

Answer (score 0):

> *"All files are properly UTF-8 encoded saved."*

Then you do not need/**must not** use `utf8_encode`. This function interprets the input as ISO-8859-1 encoded and converts the bytes to their UTF-8 equivalents. You're screwing up your string yourself.

Comment: I just removed the UTf_ENCODE. But the the var_dump removes the alert (NULL). string(73) "{"aps":{"alert":null,"badge":"1","sound":"default"},"e":"order","i":"12"}"

Comment: Files were saved as UTF-8. But header was missing. Added the header now. The message is send again, however the euro sign is in a diamond shape with ? in it. No EURO sign... "{"aps":{"alert":"Test special sign \ufffd","badge":"1","sound":"default"},"e":"order","i":"12"}"

Comment: A header doesn't matter at all here. Your files' encodings are screwed up, plain and simple.

Comment: I've checked all files again. apns class => UTF-8, push scripts => UTF-8, db.php => UTF-8. $message is UTF-8 incoming in the class.

Comment: How exactly have you checked that? What editor are you using to save the file and what have you saved it as and how?

Comment: After creating the JSON string, the file becomes an ASCII string. Does that make sense?

Comment: Eclipse, in navigator => file properties and than encoding.

Comment: I just know Eclipse can be very screwy; but not how to do it right. Try another text editor for a change.

Comment: "After creating the JSON string, the file becomes an ASCII string. Does that make sense?" No. ASCII string cannot contain `€` character.